# How to make Rails' format with validator dynamic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to validate the format of `exchange_rate` in my `Invoice` class:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :currency, :exchange_rate

  validates :exchange_rate, :format => { :with => exchange_rate_format }

  private

  def exchange_rate_format
    if currency != user.preference.base_currency
      DECIMAL_REGEX
    else
      ANOTHER_REGEX
    end
  end

end
```

The problem is: It doesn't work at all. I guess I need to use a `Proc` here? I never really figured out how to use it though. Maybe somebody can help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please always include the version of `Ruby` and `Rails` you are using.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a Proc or lambda so that the validation will be called at runtime.

```
validates :exchange_rate, format: { with: ->(invoice) { invoice.exchange_rate_format } }
# Note, I used Ruby 1.9 hash and lambda syntax here.
```

To do this you'll need to move the `exchange_rate_format` out of the `private` methods list since we're defining an explicit receiver (`invoice`). You can make it `protected` instead, if you'd like. Or you can put the conditional into the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with a custom validator:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  class ExchangeRateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      if !value =~ record.exchange_rate_format
        record.errors[attribute] << "your currency is weak sauce"
      end
    end  
  end

  validates :exchange_rate, exchange_rate_format: true

  # make public
  def exchange_rate_format
    if currency != user.preference.base_currency
      DECIMAL_REGEX
    else
     ANOTHER_REGEX
    end
  end
end
```